# Kubernetes object creation time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a command/method to get the time elapsed from the instance a Kubernetes object **creation command is launched**  (e.g., `kubectl create -f mydeployment-pod.yaml`),  until the Kubernetes object  (deployment/pod…) is fully created and in **running/ready state**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Sahadat: there is no native way of calculating that. However, you can use `kubectl get events` to see the `CreationTimestamp`, `firstTimestamp` and `lastTimestamp`. You can either request the output in yaml/json format by executing `kubectl get events -o yaml` or use  [custom columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns) and [fields selectors](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/) to narrow down the output, for example:

```
kubectl get events -o custom-columns=FirstSeen:.firstTimestamp,LastSeen:.lastTimestamp,Created:.CreationTimestamp
```

That of course can be adjusted according to your needs.

Comment: iam getting a table of <none> s

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can see the events and `CreationTimestamp` by `kubectl describe deployments <deployment_name>`